# Analytic function with restricted range

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

If $f (z)$ be analytic function  on $D =\{z \in\Bbb C : |z-1| <1 \}$  such that   $f (1) =1$ , if $f (z) =f (z^2)$  for each  $z\in D$ , then  which one of the following  statement is not correct ?

(a) $f (z) =[f (z) ]^2$ for each  $z\in D$

(b)  $f (z/2) =f (z) /2$  for         each $z \in D $

(c) $f (z^3) = [f (z)]^3$   for each $x  \in D$

(d) $f '(1) =0$

Is  $f (z)$  a constant  function  ?   If yes , then what is the reason?

Comment: $f(z)=z$ does not satisfy $f(z)=f(z^2)$.

Comment: Why are you confused about (a) and (c)? You already know that (b) is wrong.  It's as if you are looking for a counterexample to every option even though only one of them is false.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** For (d)

$$f'(1)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f((1+h)^2)-1}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2(1+h)f'((1+h)^2)}{1}=2f'(1)$$